# Foundation 4 drop down does not initialize for select element. Any suggestions why?

Tags: zurb-foundation

Select elements just stay the way they are. Tested in IE9, Chrome 25.

Scripts, added to page:

1. jquery.js (from foundation pack)
2. foundation.js
3. foundation.dropdown.js
4. `<script type="text/javascript">$(document).foundation();</script>`

I can not understand what this framework wants for to start working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, solved.
I should have added fundation.forms.js and "custom" class to the form, that contains select.

Comment: hey i am stuck in the same problem, i did the same thing, but the website renders 2 select dropdown, one with custom and another simple one ! ... argh !

Comment: Wang'l Pakhrin, I think error occurs in script between dropdowns initialization